# Can't get the audio file

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to play audio using this code:

```
var audio = new Audio("Assets/Tune/A#.mp3")
```

but the error is 
`GET file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/PROYEK/Assets/Tune/A net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

while I can play the audio in this code:

```
var audio = new Audio("Assets/Tune/A''.mp3");
```

how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Try rename it `ASharp` instead of `A#`

Comment: Welcome to stack. If you have code to show than just select your code and press `ctrl+k`  it will format your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, ill try that

Answer (score 1):

In a URL the character `#` indicates the end of the local path (or query string) and start of the fragment identifier.

If you want to use it in the local path you need to express it as `%23`.

Answer (score 0):

`#` is understood as an anchor and disregarded when retrieving the file. You may try to urlencode it (transforming it into `%23`) or as other suggested renaming your file.

Answer (score -1):

```
var audio = new Audio("~/Assets/Tune/A.mp3");
```

~ tells the roor directory.
 and give proper name to the file.

Comment: I don't think that `~` has any standard meaning in HTML URLs.